# Python solving goniometric equation

Tags: python, python-3.x, equation, trigonometry

I use Python. I have formulas like `sin(a)=v1` and `cos(a)=v2`. In math, I would do `arcsin(v1)` and `arccos(v2)` to find sollution of this equation. Is there some nice way how to solve this kind of equations in Python? Something like `solve(v1,v2) -> angle`?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Where you have `sin`, you have `asin` or `arcsin`. Or `atan2`/`arctan`/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`atan2(y,x)` should answer your question. Here is the doctring:

```
>>> help(math.atan2)
Help on built-in function atan2 in module math:

atan2(...)
    atan2(y, x)

    Return the arc tangent (measured in radians) of y/x.
    Unlike atan(y/x), the signs of both x and y are considered.
```

Comment: Nice to note that `atan`, `asin` or `acos` each correspond to 2 possible angle values.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please consider [accepting the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @google2: If this answer was useful, please accept it. You have a lot of questions with answers, you have never accepted a single one. Please consider going through them and accept (and upvote) useful answers, it's the nice thing to do: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/376604